# have to take MAX quantity price in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two different tables `('product', 'quantity_break')` each table has a connection with `'product_code'` quantity table has multiple quantity and price for each `product_code.

So I have to display only `('product_code','product_name',max(quantity),maximum quantity price)`.

Please help me with how to do the query in Laravel.

**product Table Views**

```
id  product_code    product_name

1    123             Testing
2    1234            Testing 1234
```

**quantity_break Table View**

```
id   qty_pro_code    qty   price

1    123             50     20.00
2    123             60     18.00
3    123             70     15.00

4    1234            50     25.00
5    1234            60     23.00
```

**This is my table view for each table I want to take the product_code 123 quantity 70 price (15.00) and product_code 1234 quantity 70 price (23.00)**

And this is how I attempt the query

```
$arr["product"] = DB::table('product')
                ->join('quantity_break', 'quab_product_code', '=', 'prod_product_code')
                ->select('product.prod_product_code','product.product_name','quantity_break.quab_product_code','quantity_break.quab_quantity','quantity_break.quab_price')
                ->max('quantity_break.quab_quantity')
                ->get();
```

But It's giving and error like this

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function get() on integer
```

Comment: You should be able to query the table and group it by product code and order it by price. Can you show an example of how you have attempted this question?

Answer (score 0):

`Max()` indirectly executes the query and returns the max value of the column. So no need to call `get()` in this context, simply doing the following should work.

```
$max = DB::table('product')
    ->join('quantity_break', 'quab_product_code', '=', 'prod_product_code')
    ->select('product.prod_product_code','product.product_name','quantity_break.quab_product_code','quantity_break.quab_quantity','quantity_break.quab_price')
    ->max('quantity_break.quab_quantity');
```

Comment: I try this and I checked with dd($max) it's showing only 5000

Comment: probably the correct answer then? or something is wrong with your join.

Answer (score -1):

This is code I use it's working perfectly. Help By @nipun tharuksha

```
$max = DB::table('product')
                    ->select(['product.*',DB::raw('MAX(quab_quantity) AS qty')])
                    ->LeftJoin('quantity_break', 'quab_product_code', '=', 'prod_product_code')
                    ->groupBy('prod_product_code')
                    ->get();
    
            
            $pro = array();
            foreach ($max as $wt)
            {
              $maCode=DB::table('quantity_break')->where('quab_product_code','=',$wt->prod_product_code)>where('quab_quantity','=',$wt->qty)->get();
                           
                array_push($pro,$maCode);
    
            }
    
            return view('product',compact('pro');
```